Reset Button Not Clearing Date Selection in Date Range Picker Widget Angular Material
I have a reset button in the date range picker, but when I try to reset the selected dates using the reset button, it resets the models but not the selection in the date range picker widget.
Basic date range picker - StackBlitz
Steps to reproduce:
Open the date range picker widget.
Select a date range.
Click the reset button.
Observe that while the underlying models are reset, the date selection in the date range picker widget remains unchanged.
Expected Behavior
I was expecting the date range picker widget to completely clear the selected dates and reset to its default state when the reset button is clicked, along with resetting the underlying models.
Actual Behavior
The actual behavior is that when the reset button is clicked, the underlying models are reset, but the selected dates in the date range picker widget remain highlighted and do not clear.
Environment

Angular: ^19.0.0-next.2
CDK/Material: ^19.0.0-next.2
Browser(s): Chrome
Operating System (e.g. Windows, macOS, Ubuntu): Windows and Ubuntu


It could be a bug, you can raise in angular material github and get it clarified.
As a workaround, which is simply to close the date-range picker, when the reset button is pressed, when the view is recreated, the bug goes away.
@ViewChild(MatDateRangePicker) dateRangePicker!: MatDateRangePicker<any>;
dateRangeForm: FormGroup;
...

...
resetDateRange() {
  this.dateRangePicker.close(); // <- changed here!
  this.dateRangeForm.reset();
  this.cdr.detectChanges();
}
...

Stackblitz Demo

Hi @Naren Murali, Thank you for your response. I don't want to close date range picker widget, It should remain open and selection should get cleared.

@SantoshShinde I think its a minor bug in angular material, you can raise a issue on their github page to confirm it, as a temporary workaround you can also close and reopen the calendar, that also fixes the issue, if that is ok, will update my answer
